# How can I access my localhost:3000 backend from my Android mobile phone

Tags: android, react-native, server, adb

I have implemented a react native app and I need to run it on my android phone. So I have run it on my mobile phone, but I can't log into that app because I think there no connection between react app and its backend.
My backend runs on localhost:3000. It is the node express backend. My database also in my local machine. It is MSSQL. How can I connect with the backend(server).

Example code : This is the way I fetch data wen run android emulator in my local machine on windows OS

```
const send = async() => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
        fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/customer/get-complaints-by-statusID", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authentication': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                statusID: 2,.................
```

Comment: Did you check your web services running or not either by using postman or curl or something else?

Comment: `My backend runs on localhost:3000` So it runs on the same device as your app is running on we can conclude from 'localhost'. As every device is its own localhost. Also your Android phone.

Comment: Yes i had run this app in android emulator, there was no any problem. now i need to run it on my android phone. Please guide me. Im new to this field.

Comment: Check your firewall. Also 10.0.2.2 looks more like an IP in a virtual network rather than a local one (as a convention, they are usually 192.168.x.x)